# Return list type java entity field with jpql or native sql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql, native-sql

I have the following entites in java:

```
A {
 Long id;
 List<B> elements
}

B {
 Long id;
 String name;
}
```

I want to write a query where I can retrieve all of the rows from table 'A' where it's element has a certain 'name' value. So if the filter value is X, and the Entity 'Q' from table 'A' has two relation in table 'B', like {id=1, name=X}, {id=2, name=Y}, then I want both of them in the parsed java object. Let me show you and example:

```
A table

id
1
2
3
4
5

B table
id  name    A_id
1   X       1
2   Y       1
3   X       2
4   W       4
5   X       3
6   X       4
7   Y       5
```

If I am filtering for name=X, the result should be like this:

```
[
    {
        id=1; 
        elements=[
            {id=1, name=X}, 
            {id=2, name=Y}
        ]
    },
    {
        id=2; 
        elements=[
            {id=3, name=X}
        ]
    },
    {
        id=3; 
        elements=[
            {id=5, name=X}
        ]
    },
    {
        id=4; 
        elements=[
            {id=4, name=W},
            {id=6, name=X}
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there any single sql query where I can achive this? I don't want to employ EAGER fetching method.